# Programs for contolling the execution of bash scripts

Tags: linux, macos, bash, cron, at

Can anyone recommend a GUI based program to control the execution of bash scripts according to time/interval? I'm already familiar with both **cron** and **at** and looking for recommended alternatives. A command line program might be fine as well, I'm primarily looking for ease of use and flexibility when it comes to altering the time/interval for the execution of jobs. Ideally this would run on both Linux and Mac OS. Thanks.

**Edit**: Just to make things clear, this is not for me but for a course I'm teaching within a Humanities/Arts department. Sometimes the command line is scary to a novice. My approach has been to demonstrate certain problem solving using the (in this case) OSX interface, or a utility with a GUI and then dropping down to the command line to do the same thing. I do this to "soften" the move from the GUI to the terminal. Additionally, this approach seems to help students see that the answer to a specific problem/technique can then be abstracted to a more general set of problems/techniques.

Comment: "Ease of use and flexibility" sound surjective. Could you please remind me of why `cron` is not easy to use/not flexible?

Comment: @ksh you don't really mean "remind me" do you? I think you're saying that you don't believe that using cron could be inflexible or easy for someone. Saying "remind me," rather than asking in what cases these utilities might be difficult to use makes you sound a bit like a sarcastic 12 year old.

Comment: Well no, put it in context. You (or whomever you are trying to teach) are using it with shell scripts. If one can use and write shell scripts, what's so "scary to a novice" about cron? You just specify five numbers for each job. That's all.

Comment: By the way, I was not trying to be sarcastic. As I mentioned, "ease of use and flexibility" are rather surjective, so we need more information about what kind of "ease of use" you have in mind.

Comment: Now that I know what you are trying to teach, hey, isn't this a perfect example of *why you should use the command line for productivity*? If you provide a GUI program, folks (in Humanities/Arts) will choose to be lazy and use GUI only. However, most of the time, a GUI program can't match the power and flexibility of CLI, especially in the case of `cron` and `launchd`. I guess even if there is such a program, it would just be a wrapper around `launchd` (and honestly I haven't heard of any scheduler for *shell scripts* — application schedulers might or might not work for scripts, not sure).

Comment: You're assuming that a student in the Arts/Humanities doesn't want to learn the command line, or doesn't find it interesting, which is not necessarily the case. Conversely, would you assume that Science, Engineering, and Math students have no interest in the Humanities/Art and would be "lazy?" This is also not necessarily the case. Thanks for the last part of your last message, perhaps an application scheduler might work.

Comment: Maybe I should have said "most of them", and maybe I shouldn't have used "lazy" — most of them just haven't seen the power and flexibility of the command line. Which is why you are teaching it right? (I mean, a curious student would figure this stuff out all by him/herself. The Internet has tons of information.)

Comment: Yes, I would say that all of them in this particular class get quite excited about the power of the CLI. However, many students in this class have never been in a situation where they need to think about file paths, moving around the system, reading man pages, thinking about users/permissions, etc. it's foreign territory. I agree that the web has a huge amount of information, but learning to see what information is useful takes time and depends on developing literacy in the subject. I'd like to give students at different skill levels different options. Also, wget blew them away.

Comment: Interesting. "wget blew them away" — "blew away" in the good sense or bad sense? I mean, amazed, or scared away? There are tons of command line wizardry you can demonstrate, by the way. Like downloading thousands of files/images with one command, which for most people would take click (option click), click, click, ... Not to mention text processing wizardry with sed and awk one-liners.

Comment: In the positive sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it personally, but [Cronnix](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/7486/cronnix) may be the tool that you're looking for.

Alternately, considering that your goal is '*to "soften" the move from the GUI to the terminal*', you could use:

http://www.corntab.com/pages/crontab-gui

to both help teach the basics of cron and to ease the transition to the CLI.  It uses a graphical web interface to build a line which a user could then be cut and paste into the crontab file.

Comment: Glad I could help.